# AspectJ :: Surefire tests gives NoSuchMethodError 

Tags: aspectj, surefire

I'm doing the compile time AspectJ weaving on existing classes, that is working beautifully in eclipse(AJDT). But when I run test in in maven using surefire , the test cases of this class where the aspects are applied are failing. I'm quite sure the weaving is happening correctly, it looks like a class path issue. Following is the error when I execute the surefire test.

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.online.station.OBSDescriptorBrokerageMortgageRemovalAspect.aspectOf()Lcom/online/station/OBSDescriptorBrokerageMortgageRemovalAspect;
>       at com.online.station.delegate.fundstransfer.AuthorizeAccForTransfDelegImpl.unpackResponse(AuthorizeAccForTransfDelegImpl.java:111)

Following is my surefire plugin config in pom.xml

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <forkMode>once</forkMode>
                <argLine>
                    -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                </argLine>
                <useSystemClassloader>true</useSystemClassloader>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/WebTestCase.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I tried various things but it didn't work, any suggestions will be greately appreciated !!

Is there any need to have a aop.xml for this to work ? 
 Following is the aspectj plugin info.

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.3</version>
<configuration>
    <verbose>true</verbose>
    <complianceLevel>${jdk.source.version}</complianceLevel>
    <target>${jdk.target.version}</target>
    <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
    <weaveMainSourceFolder>true</weaveMainSourceFolder>
    <includes>
        <!-- Class AspectClass1 and dependencies -->
        <include>**/AspectClass1*</include>
        <include>**/Class2*</include>
        <include>**/Class3*</include>
        <include>**/Class4*</include>
        <include>**/Class5*</include>
        <include>**/Class6*</include>
        <include>**/Class7*</include>
        <include>**/Class8*</include>

    </includes>
</configuration>
<executions>
    <execution>
    <goals>
        <goal>compile</goal>                <goal>test-compile</goal>       </goals>
    </execution>
   </executions>
```

As I need compile time weaving only, I have no aop.xml configured.

Any help on tjis please !

Thanks !!
Girish

Answer (score 1):

Three suggestions:

1. Make sure that your aspectj plugin for maven is configured correctly.  If you have any questions about that, paste that part of your pom.xml in your question above.
2. Make sure that your aop.xml references all of the required aspects.
3. Make sure that your aspect-path/in-path is configured properly.

Comment: Hey Andrew ... thanks again. I have added the aspectj plugin details in the question. I'm bit confused , I'm doing the compile time weaving ( not load time ) then also I need aop.xml ? Is there any way I can provide aspectpath on inpath in pom ?

Comment: Girish, did you ever get an answer to this?  I have also wondered if the aop.xml file is needed.

Comment: Must have missed that question the first time around.  No, the aop.xml is not needed for compile-time weaving.